# Download and Run script in Linux Terminal?

Tags: linux, bash

I am running Linux.

I'm writing an installer in Bash for an application I wrote.

The installer needs to be able to download different Bash scripts and run them automatically?

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Take a look at [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/).

It comes pre-installed on *most* Linux OSs.

It works as simply as typing `wget <the-url-to-download>`.

In your case, you'll probably want to do something along these lines:

```
wget https://www.example.com/files/coreinstall.sh -O new-filename.sh
chmod +x new-filename.sh
./new-filename.sh
```

Be careful not to mistype the URL, because the above script will download and run whatever is at that URL.

### Alternatively, use curl.

If `wget` is not installed and `curl` is available, use it instead of `wget` with `-o` (lower-case) instead of the `-O` switch:

```
curl https://www.example.com/files/coreinstall.sh -o new-filename.sh
```

Comment: If you don't need to keep the script lying around: `wget $url -O - | sh`

Comment: That would work, but as he is using bash, he would need to make sure he starts his scripts with `#!/bin/bash`, or replace the `sh` on the end to `bash`, i.e. `wget $url -O - | bash`.